# Algorithm | Given an array[] and k, find number of subsets sum multiple of k

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, subset-sum

Given an `array[]` of positive integers and another integer `k`, I have to find number of subset whose sum is multiple of `k`(`sum` is evenly divisible by `k`).

For example,

```
array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}, k = 3
```

Subset sums are,

```
1 = 1
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
2 = 2
2 + 3 = 5
2 + 3 + 4 = 9
3 = 3
3 + 4 = 7
4 = 4
```

Thus, `{3, 6, 9}` are multiple of `k = 3` and the answer is `3`. For the same array above and `k = 2`, answer will be `4 = {6, 10, 2, 4}`
How to implement it efficiently for array size **1 million**.

Comment: What's the range of the elements and of k? Are you familiar with classic subset sum problem DP solution?

Comment: both are in integer range in C. Yes i know classic one. but seems it wont work here.

Comment: `both are in integer range in C` I wish that was a properly defined size :(

Comment: lets say `2<=k<=10000`. how would you solve it?

Comment: Are you familiar with subset sum problem? Obviously this problem is NP-Complete, so if elements are in relatively small range - pseudo polynomial solution is probably the best you can do, and you can do it exactly like regular subset sum problem solution. in `O(n*W)`, where `n` is number of elements and `W` is the sum of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a close variant of [Subset Sum Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), and as the original, it is NP-Complete (Reduction from [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) is trivial).

It can be solved using Dynamic Programming by following the recursive formulas:

```
D(0,0) = true
D(0,x) = false       x > 0
D(i,x) = false       x < 0
D(i,x) = D(i-1,x) OR D(i-1,x-arr[i])
```

In here, `D(i,x)` is true if and only if you can use a subset of the first `i` elements to build the number `x`.

This can be calculated efficiently using Dynamic Programming.

When you are done, simply count the number of values of `i` such that `D(n,k*i) = true`

This will take `O(n*W)` time where `n` is the number of elements, and `W` is the sum of them.

Comment: Doesn't this approach also take `O(n*W)` space?  That may be acceptable, of course, but it might also be prohibitive.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Since you need only the previous line at each point (you always go to `D(i-1,...)`, you only need the current and last row, so it can be done in `O(W)` space. There is no real way to do it more efficiently than pseudo-polynomial time, unless P=NP, as solving it efficiently immidately allows one to solve Partition Problem.

Comment: You can do the weight indexing mod `k` for an `O(n*k)`-time algorithm.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Maybe I am missing something, but won't it only give you if there is `i` such that the subset sums to `i` - but will not tell you what is its value (or how many such `i` values exist, which is what you need)?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a clear use of using recursion.

for each value in array

test value by itself

test all combinations of remaining array, both with value added and without value added.

Comment: did you see the limit in question? @redlum

Comment: I didn't, but it probably wouldn't change my answer. If you wrote code that implemented it this way and it didn't meet your needs, then you can tell us what's missing.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Light year is a distance measure :(